# There is no connected camera message with built in FaceTime camera

Tags: camera, facetime

Anyone run into "There is no connected camera" message while using any of the camera applications (Messages, PhotoBooth, Skype, etc.)? I tried force quitting all the applications that use the camera but with no luck. Even tried `sudo killall VDCAssistant` without any luck. Restarting the machine fixes the issue, but it is highly annoying to do so every day. I am running 10.8.1 on 2012 MacBook Pro.

Comment: It used to be fixed that `sudo killall VDCAssistant` before, later with only restart. Now both do not work. I do not know what to do yet. There is nno VDC including process after a reboot to kill it.

Comment: Maybe helps: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251231383

Answer (score 10):

From [osxdaily](http://osxdaily.com/2013/12/27/fix-there-is-no-connected-camera-error-mac/):

- Quit all open apps that may try to use the FaceTime camera
- Open Terminal, found in the /Applications/Utilities directory in OS X
- Enter the following command string exactly, then hit return:

  ```
  sudo killall VDCAssistant
  ```
- Enter the administrator password when requested, this is required to execute a command with superuser privileges as prefixed by sudo
- Relaunch the app that was attempting to use the camera

Or... Use **Activity Monitor**, search for `VDC` and **force quit** it.

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is not Application-specific, nor User-specific, and your computer clearly recognizes the iSight, you should try reseting the [**SMC**](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964).

To do so, just:

1. Shut down the computer.
2. Plug in the MagSafe power adapter to a power source, connecting it to the Mac if its not already connected.
3. On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side) <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd> and the power button at the same time.
4. Release all the keys and the power button at the same time.
5. Press the power button to turn on the computer.

Comment: Resetting the SMC has no effect on the camera.  https://support.apple.com/de-de/HT201295

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your antivirus software? Ensure it's not blocking your webcam